# How to disable Activitiy toolbar's divider in Fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, user-interface, android-fragments

How can I disable `toolbar's divider` in `Fragment.` I have attached two Images

The UI I want

[image: The UI I want]

and

The UI I am getting

[image: The UI I am getting].

I have this layout for a `Fragment' and I don't know how can I disable that irritating Divider line between my`Toolbar` and 'View'. Suggestions/Help needed. 
Attached my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:src="@drawable/backimage"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:drawableTint="@color/black"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:focusedByDefault="false"
    android:hint="Search" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp">

</GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try setting `app:elevation="0dp"` for tool bar

Comment: @Redman I already tried setting up `elevation' but nothing worked.

Comment: post your layout file

Comment: @Redman This layout is for my Fragment and I have Activity with NoActionBar and creating my own Toolbar with AppBar Layout. I don't know what point I am not getting but I already tried setting up elevation.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm if you were using appbar layout,  try setting android:stateListAnimator="@null"   and  setOutlineProvider(null)  to appbar

Comment: @Redman I tried these also but nothing working.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

**Or You can Also Use**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Also add theme in Manifest like this in activity

```
  <activity 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: second method ,Did you try??

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom action bar in your XML. Just like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Still facing the problem after updating too.

Comment: There is no error. It is I am not getting what I want in the UI. I just want to remove divider line from Toolbar. Plus I am working on Fragment Layout.